# Unknown symbol - sort of distant switch

Tags: symbol

I have some technical drawings and I am looking for the name of a pair of components (or maybe two disctinct components) whose symbols I cannot identify. I understand one is a type of switch controlled by the other component which is connected to a NI-6008 USB card. The two are drawn separately but I do not know if they are linked in reality, simply avoiding additional wires on the schematic.

What are the following symbols?

[image]

Comment: Relay coil and relay contact - go google electrical relay

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Done (hopefully) @juca

Comment: Andy’s the fast shooter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: -

[image]

There are many variations on this general theme that you should you google: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://eblogbd.com/basic-of-relay/).

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/164240717642093364/)